# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python-unicode

I'm very new to Python coding and have run into an issue while trying to upgrade some code. I'm working with an app that pulls data via an API from stored data from a scan.

here is the code as it sits working

```
def _collect_one_host_scan_info(self, host_id, sid, scan_info):
    """
    The method to collect all the vulnerabilities of one host and generate the event data.
    """
    count = 0
    host_uri = self.endpoint + '/' + str(sid) + '/hosts/' + str(host_id)
    result = self.client.request(host_uri).get("content")
    # if there is exception in request, return None
    if result is None:
        _LOGGER.info("There is exception in request, return None")
        return None
    else:
        host_info = result.get("info", {})
        host_end_time = host_info.get("host_end", "")
        if self.ckpt.is_new_host_scan(host_end_time,
                                      self.config.get("start_date")):
            self.source = self.url + self.endpoint + '/' + str(
                sid) + '/hosts/' + str(host_id)
            for vuln in result.get("vulnerabilities", []):
                vuln["sid"] = sid
                vuln["host_id"] = host_id

                #get the port info
                plugin_id = vuln.get("plugin_id", "")
                port_info = []
                if plugin_id:
                    plugin_uri = "{}/plugins/{}".format(host_uri,
                                                        plugin_id)
                    plugin_outputs = self.client.request(plugin_uri).get(
                        "content", {}).get("outputs")
                    ports = []
                    for output in plugin_outputs:
                        ports.extend(output.get("ports", {}).keys())
                    for port in ports:
                        port_elem = {}
                        port_items = re.split(r"\s*/\s*", port)
                        port_elem["port"] = int(port_items[0])
                        if port_items[1]:
                            port_elem["transport"] = port_items[1]
                        if port_items[2]:
                            port_elem["protocol"] = port_items[2]
                        port_info.append(port_elem)

                vuln = dict(vuln, **scan_info)
                vuln = dict(vuln, **host_info)
                if port_info:
                    vuln["ports"] = port_info
                entry = NessusObject(
                    vuln.get("timestamp"), self.sourcetype, self.source,
                    vuln)
                self._print_stream(entry)
                count += 1
    return count
```

The data that is being pulled from looks like this

```
"outputs": [
    {
        "ports": {
            "445 / tcp / cifs": [
                {
                    "hostname": "computer.domain.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        "has_attachment": 0,
        "custom_description": null,
        "plugin_output": "\nPath : c:\\program files (x86)\\folder\\bin\\fax.exe\nUsed by services : RFDB\nFile write allowed for groups : Domain Users\nFull control of directory allowed for groups : Domain Users\n\nPath : c:\\program files (x86)\\folder\\bin\\faxrpc.exe\nUsed by services : RFRPC\nFile write allowed for groups : Domain Users\nFull control of directory allowed for groups : Domain Users\n\nPath : c:\\program files (x86)\\folder\\bin\\faxserv.exe\nUsed by services : RFSERVER\nFile write allowed for groups : Domain Users\nFull control of directory allowed for groups : Domain Users\n`,
        "hosts": null,
        "severity": 3
    }
```

with the working code the return is

```
ports{}.port 445
ports{}.protocol tcp
ports{}.transport cifs
```

What I really would like is to grab the "plugin_output" data with the "port" data

I'm currently just trying to replace the "port" data with "plugin_output" data

```
#get the output info
            plugin_id = vuln.get("plugin_id", "")
            output_info = []
            if plugin_id:
                plugin_uri = "{}/plugins/{}".format(host_uri,
                                                    plugin_id)
                plugin_outputs = self.client.request(plugin_uri).get(
                    "content", {}).get("outputs")
                outputs = []
                for output in plugin_outputs:
                    outputs.extend(output.get("plugin_output", "").keys())
                for plugin in plugin_outputs:
                    plugin_elem = {}
                    plugin_items = re.split(r"nPath\s*", plugin)
                    plugin_elem["location1"] = plugin_items[0]
                    if plugin_items[1]:
                        plugin_elem["location2"] = plugin_items[1]
                    if plugin_items[2]:
                        plugin_elem["location3"] = plugin_items[2]
                    output_info.append(plugin_elem)

            vuln = dict(vuln, **scan_info)
            vuln = dict(vuln, **host_info)
            if output_info:
                vuln["plugin_output"] = output_info
            entry = NessusObject(
                vuln.get("timestamp"), self.sourcetype, self.source,
                vuln)
            self._print_stream(entry)
            count += 1
```

what I've done as you can see if just replace the "ports" data with "plugin_output" data and the error received is 
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute key

Comment: The JSON sometimes does not have the "plugin_output" field.

Answer (score 0):

Well after further efforts I was able to figure out what I needed to do with the code. It was much easier than I thought it would be but sometime when learning a new language its hard to envision what is needed. Code posted below.

```
 def _collect_one_host_scan_info(self, host_id, sid, scan_info):
     """
     The method to collect all the vulnerabilities of one host and generate 
     the event data.
     """
     count = 0
     host_uri = self.endpoint + '/' + str(sid) + '/hosts/' + str(host_id)
     result = self.client.request(host_uri).get("content")
     # if there is exception in request, return None
     if result is None:
         _LOGGER.info("There is exception in request, return None")
         return None
     else:
         host_info = result.get("info", {})
         host_end_time = host_info.get("host_end", "")
         if self.ckpt.is_new_host_scan(host_end_time,
                                       self.config.get("start_date")):
             self.source = self.url + self.endpoint + '/' + str(
                 sid) + '/hosts/' + str(host_id)
             for vuln in result.get("vulnerabilities", []):
                 vuln["sid"] = sid
                 vuln["host_id"] = host_id
                 plugin_id = vuln.get("plugin_id", "")

                 # get plugin_output data
                 plugin_output_info = []
                 if plugin_id:
                     plugin_uri = "{}/plugins/{}".format(host_uri,
                                                         plugin_id)
                     plugin_outputs = self.client.request(plugin_uri).get(
                         "content", {}).get("outputs", [])
                     data_output = []
                     for output in plugin_outputs:
                         items = output.get("plugin_output", 'no value')
                         item = str(items)
                         #clean = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-()_*.(:\\)]', ' ', item)
                         plugin_output_info.append(item)

                 # get the port info        
                 port_info = []
                 if plugin_id:
                     plugin_uri = "{}/plugins/{}".format(host_uri,
                                                         plugin_id)
                     plugin_outputs = self.client.request(plugin_uri).get(
                         "content", {}).get("outputs", [])
                     ports = []
                     for output in plugin_outputs:
                         ports.extend(output.get("ports", {}).keys())
                     for port in ports:
                         port_elem = {}
                         port_items = re.split(r"\s*/\s*", port)
                         port_elem["port"] = int(port_items[0])
                         if port_items[1]:
                             port_elem["transport"] = port_items[1]
                         if port_items[2]:
                             port_elem["protocol"] = port_items[2]
                         port_info.append(port_elem)

                 vuln = dict(vuln, **scan_info)
                 vuln = dict(vuln, **host_info)
                 if port_info:
                     vuln["ports"] = port_info
                 if plugin_output_info:
                     vuln["plugin_output"] = plugin_output_info
                 entry = NessusObject(
                     vuln.get("timestamp"), self.sourcetype, self.source,
                     vuln)
                 self._print_stream(entry)
                 count += 1
     return count
```